# Reading file between two points

Tags: java, io, newline, readfile

I have got following file:

file.csv

```
header:2013/01/01, shasum: 495629218484151218892233214
content:data,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l
content:data,q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p
content:data,z,x,c,v,b,n,m
footer:2013/01/01 EOF
```

I need to calculate the hash of content. In other words I need to calculate hash of file contents without header and footer and make sure it matches with the one provided in the header from source. I tried reading file line by line using `scanner` and leaving out header and footer.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("filename"));
String header = reader.nextLine();
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
    line = reader.nextLine();
    if(reader.hasNextLine()){
        md.update(line.getBytes());
        md.update(NEW_LINE.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Here I don't know where file is coming from. It might be coming from Windows or Unix. So how could I know what `NEW_LINE` to use. For that I have written this dirty hack.

```
int i;
while((i = br.read()) != -1){
    if(i == '\r'){
        if(br.read() == '\n'){
            NEW_LINE = "\r\n";
            break;
        }
    } else if(i == '\n'){
        NEW_LINE = "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically it is looking for the first sequence of either `\r\n` or `\n`. Whatever it encounters first, it assumes that to be the newline character.

This will definitely land me in trouble if my file is a mix of both CRLF and LF. I might benefit from a reader to which I can provide two offsets and it gives me back content between those two offsets. Like so:

`reader.read(15569, 236952265);`

I believe the two offsets that I want can be calculated. Any suggestions from community greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not to include CRLF and LF into your hash? Regardless to what you expect

Comment: I think he wants the hash to be identical for the same file from either system's newline standard.

Comment: Could you not consume 15569 characters and then ignore them?  From that point you could continue until you got to your endpoint...?

Comment: @archer how can you determine if line ended with LF or CRLF using scanner?

Comment: No way to determine. I propose just `md.update(line)` regardles to what NEWLINE is used. In that case file with same content made on different (Unix, Windows) machines will has same MD5 hash. Even having different NEWLINE characters.

Comment: @archer ah, I misread your comment, sorry. It depends on how hash was calculated.

Comment: You are going to have trouble with non-ASCII characters as well, if you have Unix and Windows sources

Comment: @archer We need Sha-224 hash and not md5. The problem is in `md.update(line)` the `line` string that passed can be either obtained from `Scanner.nextLine()` or `BufferedReader.readline()`. In both the cases the `line` is chomped and the new line character(s) is(are) not preserved.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I can read and ignore the initial characters. But how would I determine when to stop reading. Remember I need to leave out the footer as well. Btw you are right about matching the calculated hash with one already present in file header.

Comment: @artbristol We are using ISO-8859-1 charset. I have taken care that my reader always reads ISO-8859-1. In my actual code `Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("filename", "ISO-8859-1"));`. But left it out in this question because that is not really my concern.

Comment: Perhaps this is naive, but shouldn't there be a way to read it backwards?  Perhaps by reversing the byte stream and using Scanner normally?  You could thus parse it backward, delete the footer you consume, save this modified file temporarily, and then read it forward.  Not a very good solution, but I think it would be possible...

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Could you provide a detailed explaination as an answer? Since there are none, I will accept that.

Comment: @juzerali Just to make sure, do you need help finding the starting and stopping points, or just creating a reader that will only consume what is between those two after you've already calculated that?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I am yet to find a reader that can read the file between two points. So if you could even just provide a reader, I think I will be able to figure out the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than how I supposed in the comments, we should simply use the `RandomAccessFile` class!

```
// Load in the data file in read-only mode:
RandomAccessFile randFile = new RandomAccessFile("inputFileName.txt", "r");

// (On your own): Calculate starting byte to read from
// (On your own): Calculate ending byte to read from

// Discard header and footer.
randFile.setLength(endingPoint);
randFile.seek(startingPoint);

// Discard newlines of any kind as they are read in.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(endingPoint - startingPoint);
String currentLine = "";
while(currentLine != null)
{
  sb.append(currentLine);
  currentLine = randFile.readLine();
}

// hash your String contained in your StringBuilder without worrying about
// header, footer or newlines of any kind.
```

Note this code is not production quality as it does not catch exceptions and may have some off-by-one errors.  I highly recommend reading the documentation on the RandomAccessFile class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine()

I hope this helps.  If I am off base, let me know and I'll give it another shot.

Comment: My problem is not the new line character at the end or beginning of my content. My problem is all the new line characters in between.`randFile.readLine()` will chomp off the new line characters at the end of line and hence it won't be included in the hash. The hash which I receive in header has been calculated with new line characters included.

Comment: @juzerali Oh, that is straightforward to fix.  You need to use readFully() which will give you all of the bytes in an array you specify.  I thought you wanted to remove the newlines from the body as well.

Comment: Will get me in trouble if file size is too large. In our case we are expecting more than 70k rows in the file. I guess I will have to write an algorithm to read few chunks at a time.

Comment: @juzerali Your hash function is all you need to worry about.  The algorithm to read in a few chunks at a time shouldn't be too bad.  Just adjust the code from using readFully() to read() which will read a byte at a time or an overloaded version will read as many bytes as you tell it.  It's all in the javadoc I posted a link to.